# Usb type c Splitter

Tags: usb

I am getting a Nintendo Switch charging dock which comes with one USB type c male port to charge a controller, but I have 2 controllers and I'm looking for a USB female to male Y-splitter or anything with two USB type c male outputs to charge, the best would be a hard block type thing to support the controllers but anything will do. Lastly if anyone has a cable management idea for this, If I find a Y splitter to make it a real charging dock, holds the cables in place

Answer (score 1):

I use [this one](http://www.lmall.my/aukey-cb-c48-usb-c-hub-3-0-5-ports-hub-splitter-cable-adapter-aukey-F513606-2007-01-Sale-I.htm) (it used to be available on amazon) for my phone to charge it while attaching other usb-c devices (the ports on top can be used to plug in other devices, while the port on the side is used to provide power for the host device). I'm still looking for a smaller usb-c hub that only features two female usb-c ports, but I don't think it exists yet.

Comment: It's not amazing. Only splits one usb-c into two usb-c out but it's at least something!